# Can't harvest/forage bushes

Tags: stardew-valley

I find myself unable to harvest/forage bushes that appear to have fruits.

In the summer there are bushes with pink berry looking dots and all I can do is shake it - nothing pops off.

I'm a forager level 5 - am I perhaps too low? Is there some event that triggers this ability?

The bushes in question look like these:

[image]

Comment: Could you take a screenshot?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Added. Maybe are the pink berries different sizes and I'm just assuming they are full grown? It was even up to the last days of Summer that I still couldn't harvest any however.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those pink things in the bushes are just flowers, you cannot harvest them. Incidentally, no harvest item grows on bushes during the Summer.

Comment: Oh good. Thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: @Enigma Yeah, I've been there too.

Comment: Haven't we all. Luckily I had friends playing and literally everyone asked at one point or another if we could harvest those pink things in the bushes during summer lol

Comment: But they *look* as if you could harvest them!